# what should i write in the settings.py to import my Template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, pythonanywhere

**I have deployed my project on pythonanywhere and there i am getting an error that template does not exist**

[image]

**It's working properly on local host**

File directory

[image]

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Can someone tell what should i add my template DIRS

Comment: The templates directory should be all lowercase, it's a Python convention to have lowercase names for all modules/directories

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this into DIRS

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Templates')],
```

after that you can get your html files like 'Main/test.html'

And yeah it's better to put names in lowercase